# OOP How to tell which class method gets invoked from implemented interface

Tags: java, spring, oop

If you have one interface called A that has one method signature called print; Now if you have 3 classes implementing A and you call A.print how do you know which class method gets invoked. THERE IS NO NEWING OF AN OBJECT

```
public interface A()
{
  public void print(){}
}
@Component
public class B implements A
{
 public void print()
 {
   system.out.print("B");
 }
}
@Component
public class c implements A
{
 public void print()
 {
   system.out.print("C");
 }
}
@Component
public class d implements A
{
 public void print()
 {
   system.out.print("d");
 }
}


public class runner()
{
    @Autowired
    private A aThing_;

    aThing_.print();
}
```

Comment: nitpicking:  Classes in Java should start with Uppercase therefore class `c` and `d` should be `C` and `D`

Comment: @gtgaxiola I'm aware, thank you. Convention isnt my concern

Comment: Why do you want to know which class method is invoked? Can you not simply do `aThing_.getClass()` to figure out what class is it? That is what polymorphism suppose to do.

Comment: Looks like it's a Spring question, more than Java polymorphism.

Comment: What are you really trying to do? I believe you could solve this problem in some other way.

Comment: @Kai this is a Spring-Framework example. I'm trying to understand which one gets called without newing a specific class

Comment: @stackoverflow have you tried running this? What happens? I am not sure about Spring, but I use Google Guice extensively where you can provide hints to the container of what Class to instantiate by use of annotations, something like `bind(CreditCardProcessor.class).annotatedWith(PayPal.class).to(PayPalCreditCardProcessor.class)`

Comment: It is important to note that this is not really an OOP question as such, but it is more about "How Spring resolves dependency injection when there are more than one implementation?'. Then, you will probably find your answer easily. Just run the code, it will probably throw an exception, explaining the problem. Then you can search more to find, how to solve it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

An interface defines an interaction contract or, in other words, defines a set of methods that every class implementing that interface should provide.

Oracle's answer to the question, [What's an Interface?](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/concepts/interface.html) is:

> As you've already learned, objects define their interaction with the
>   outside world through the methods that they expose. Methods form the
>   object's interface with the outside world; the buttons on the front of
>   your television set, for example, are the interface between you and
>   the electrical wiring on the other side of its plastic casing. You
>   press the "power" button to turn the television on and off.

The invocation depends on the type of the object implementing the interface.

```
A interface = new B();
```

You'll be invoking `B`'s `print` method's implementation for the `print` method defined in the `A` interface.

*EDIT:* The point of an interface is defining the interaction with an object regardless of its actual type. That code seems to be the autoscanning of a group of components behind the same interface to show that you can define a set of different components to handle the same situation in a different way, given the context.

AFAIK the autowire defaults to the field's name. You can define which interface implementation you want to inject with the `@Qualifier("CLASS_NAME_HERE")` annotation alongside with `@Autowire`.

You might want to check [this](http://static.springsource.org/spring/docs/3.0.0.M3/reference/html/ch04s11.html).

Comment: There is no NEW in this example

Comment: There is an implicit new, when Spring instantiates the objects to create the components that live in the container. The `@Autowired` annotation tells Spring to inject the corresponding dependency.

Comment: so how do we know which of the classes implementing the interface will be invoked in the above

Answer (score 1):

It will call the method version from the class whose object invokes it

```
A ob = new B(); 
ob.print()// will invoke method from B


A ob = new C(); 
ob.print()// will invoke method from C
```

---

**See**

- [Java Polymorphism](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/IandI/polymorphism.html)

Comment: There is no newing going on in this example. This is an example from spring Framework

Comment: spring creates instance for yourself based on your configuration, so the concept remains same

Answer (score 0):

Depends on how you instantiate such Object:

For example

`private A aThing = new C();`

Will invoke `C` print method

Comment: There is no newing going on in this example

Answer (score 0):

If I understand our example correctly, you have a class Runner, to which a reference to an object which implements A is autowired.

The whole point of the interface is polymorphism. In other words, the purpose of using the interface A in this design is so that Runner doesn't need to know which implementation is being used - all Runner cares about is that the method(s) defined on A are available.

You can set up a property on A which returns some sort of type information, but (with some exceptions, I believe) that defeats part of the purpose.